# Apache Spark Data Generator Function on Databricks Not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks-community-edition

I am trying to execute the Data Generator function provided my Microsoft to test streaming data to Event Hubs.

Unfortunately, I keep on getting the error

```
Processing failure: No such file or directory
```

When I try and execute the function:

```
%scala
DummyDataGenerator.start(15)
```

Can someone take a look at the code and help decipher why I'm getting the error:

```
class DummyDataGenerator:
  streamDirectory = "/FileStore/tables/flight"
None # suppress output
```

I'm not sure how the above cell gets called into the function DummyDataGenerator

```
%scala

import scala.util.Random
import java.io._
import java.time._

// Notebook #2 has to set this to 8, we are setting
// it to 200 to "restore" the default behavior.
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 200)

// Make the username available to all other languages.
// "WARNING: use of the "current" username is unpredictable
// when multiple users are collaborating and should be replaced
// with the notebook ID instead.
val username = com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext.current.tags(com.databricks.logging.BaseTagDefinitions.TAG_USER);
spark.conf.set("com.databricks.training.username", username)

object DummyDataGenerator extends Runnable {
  var runner : Thread = null;
  val className = getClass().getName()
  val streamDirectory = s"dbfs:/tmp/$username/new-flights"
  val airlines = Array( ("American", 0.17), ("Delta", 0.12), ("Frontier", 0.14), ("Hawaiian", 0.13), ("JetBlue", 0.15), ("United", 0.11), ("Southwest", 0.18) )
  val reasons = Array("Air Carrier", "Extreme Weather", "National Aviation System", "Security", "Late Aircraft")

  val rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
  var maxDuration = 3 * 60 * 1000 // default to three minutes

  def clean() {
    System.out.println("Removing old files for dummy data generator.")
    dbutils.fs.rm(streamDirectory, true)
    if (dbutils.fs.mkdirs(streamDirectory) == false) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create temp directory.")
    }
  }

  def run() {
    val date = LocalDate.now()
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < maxDuration) {
      try {
        val dir = s"/dbfs/tmp/$username/new-flights"
        val tempFile = File.createTempFile("flights-", "", new File(dir)).getAbsolutePath()+".csv"
        val writer = new PrintWriter(tempFile)

        for (airline <- airlines) {
          val flightNumber = rand.nextInt(1000)+1000
          val deptTime = rand.nextInt(10)+10
          val departureTime = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(-deptTime)
          val (name, odds) = airline
          val reason = Random.shuffle(reasons.toList).head
          val test = rand.nextDouble()

          val delay = if (test < odds)
            rand.nextInt(60)+(30*odds)
            else rand.nextInt(10)-5

          println(s"- Flight #$flightNumber by $name at $departureTime delayed $delay minutes due to $reason")
          writer.println(s""" "$flightNumber","$departureTime","$delay","$reason","$name" """.trim)
        }
        writer.close()

        // wait a couple of seconds
        //Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(5000))

      } catch {
        case e: Exception => {
          printf("* Processing failure: %s%n", e.getMessage())
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    println("No more flights!")
  }

  def start(minutes:Int = 5) {
    maxDuration = minutes * 60 * 1000

    if (runner != null) {
      println("Stopping dummy data generator.")
      runner.interrupt();
      runner.join();
    }
    println(s"Running dummy data generator for $minutes minutes.")
    runner = new Thread(this);
    runner.run();
  }

  def stop() {
    start(0)
  }
}

DummyDataGenerator.clean()

displayHTML("Imported streaming logic...") // suppress output
```

Comment: what is the data generator function? can you post URL?

Comment: Hi Alex, its a data generator that was provided as part of a Databricks Course. Its actually a very good data generator. I have posted a link for the DBC. Once you drill down, its called 'Stream Generator'
https://github.com/cpatte7372/testrepo/blob/master/08-Streaming%20(2).dbc

Comment: are you running on community edition or Azure Databricks?

Comment: For data generation I can recommend: https://github.com/databrickslabs/dbldatagen

Comment: I am running on Community Edition.

Comment: The data generation you suggested looks good. I wish I had asked for that in the first place - instead of spending 48 hours trying to get my data generation working. Having said that, my Data Generation works beautifully on Azure Databricks .. just can't get it to work on Community Edition.
Also, do you have any examples of your data generation working?

Comment: When I attempt to run the code from your data generation
```test = (spark.range(100).withColumn("start", from_unixtime(col("id")*lit(interval(1,"hours"))).cast(TimestampType()))```
I get the error 
```TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object is not callable```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to use the Databricks Labs Data Generator on the Databricks community edition. I'm providing the instructions below:

## Running Databricks Labs Data Generator on the community edition

The Databricks Labs Data Generator is a Pyspark library so the code to generate the data needs to be Python. But you should be able to create a view on the generated data and consume it from Scala if that's your preferred language.

1. You can install the framework on the Databricks community edition by creating a notebook with the cell

> %pip install git+https://github.com/databrickslabs/dbldatagen

Once it's installed you can then use the library to define a data generation spec and by using build, generate a Spark dataframe on it.

The following example shows generation of batch data similar to the data set you are trying to generate. This should be placed in a separate notebook cell

Note - here we generate 10 million records to illustrate ability to create larger data sets. It can be used to generate datasets much larger than that

```
%python

num_rows = 10 * 1000000  # number of rows to generate
num_partitions = 8  # number of Spark dataframe partitions

delay_reasons = ["Air Carrier", "Extreme Weather", "National Aviation System", "Security", "Late Aircraft"]

# will have implied column `id` for ordinal of row
flightdata_defn = (dg.DataGenerator(spark, name="flight_delay_data", rows=num_rows, partitions=num_partitions)
                 .withColumn("flightNumber", "int", minValue=1000, uniqueValues=10000, random=True)
                 .withColumn("airline", "string", minValue=1, maxValue=500,  prefix="airline", random=True, distribution="normal")
                 .withColumn("original_departure", "timestamp", begin="2020-01-01 01:00:00", end="2020-12-31 23:59:00", interval="1 minute", random=True)
                 .withColumn("delay_minutes", "int", minValue=20, maxValue=600, distribution=dg.distributions.Gamma(1.0, 2.0))
                 .withColumn("delayed_departure",  "timestamp", expr="cast(original_departure as bigint) +  (delay_minutes * 60) ", baseColumn=["original_departure", "delay_minutes"])
                 .withColumn("reason", "string", values=delay_reasons, random=True)
                )

df_flight_data = flightdata_defn.build()

display(df_flight_data)
```

You can find information on how to generate streaming data in the online documentation at https://databrickslabs.github.io/dbldatagen/public_docs/using_streaming_data.html

You can create a named temporary view over the data so that you can access it from SQL or Scala using one of two methods:

1: use `createOrReplaceTempView`

> df_flight_data.createOrReplaceTempView("delays")

2: use options for build. In this case the name passed to the Data Instance initializer will be the name of the view

i.e

> df_flight_data = flightdata_defn.build(withTempView=True)

Comment: Hi Ronan, I attempted to query the Streaming data using the following:

df_flight_data = flightdata_defn.build(withStreaming=True, options={'rowsPerSecond': 100})  

df_flight_data.writeStream \
 .format("delta") \
 .outputMode("append") \
 .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
 .queryName("delays") \
 .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/dbldatagen/streamingDemo/checkpoint") \
 .start("/tmp/dbldatagen/streamingDemo/data")


I then used the following to query the stream

Comment: ```%sql SELECT Reason, Airline, date_format(window.end, "MMM-dd HH:mm") AS DepartureDate, Count FROM delays ORDER BY DepartureDate```
But I got the error:
```Error in SQL statement:: Table or view not found: delays;```

Comment: Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error?

Comment: In the code snippet above, you don't have a Spark SQL table or view named 'delays'

You can fix this using one of several methods:

1: change your code to select data directly from the delta format files:

i.e 

 (%sql SELECT Reason, Airline, date_format(window.end, "MMM-dd HH:mm") AS DepartureDate, Count FROM delays ORDER BY `delta`.'/tmp/dbldatagen/streamingDemo/data')

2: Create a temporary view named 'delays' over the data frame using the createOrReplaceTmpView method

3: create an external table over the data using the location you are writing to

Comment: The formatting for comments is removing some of the punctuation - i'll add the revised code in a separate answer

Comment: option 1: simply refer to the delta files in  a SQL statement:


```
%sql SELECT Reason, Airline, date_format(delayed_departure, "MMM-dd HH:mm") AS DepartureDate FROM delta.\`/tmp/dbldatagen/streamingDemo/data\` ORDER BY DepartureDate Desc

```

Comment: The data generator (`dbldatagen`) is now available as a PyPi installable package

- use `%pip install dbldatagen` to install

Answer (score 2):

This code will not work on the community edition because of this line:

```scala
val dir = s"/dbfs/tmp/$username/new-flights"
```

as there is no [DBFS fuse](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis) on Databricks community edition (it's supported only on full Databricks). It's potentially possible to make it working by:

1. Changing that directory to local directory, like, `/tmp` or something like
2. adding a code (after `writer.close()`) to list `flights-*` files in that local directory, and using `dbutils.fs.mv` to move them into `streamDirectory`

Comment: Hi Alex, after plenty of troubleshooting, I thought that to be the case. So, I did change to a local directory like dbfs:/tmp/mylocal/new-flights and /tmp/carlton@keyloop.co.uk/new-flights, but kept on getting the error ```File or Directory doesn't exist```

Comment: No. It shouldn’t be a DBFS directory, but directory on Linux of driver node

Comment: So, should ```'/tmp/mydirector/new-flight'``` work?

Comment: yes, don't forget to create it...

Comment: TBH Alex, I've been checking out the data streaming link you provided, and its excellent. Thanks again mate.