# Apache Spark Data Generator Function on Databricks to Send Data To Azure Event Hubs

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I created a question on how to use Databricks dummy data generator here [Apache Spark Data Generator Function on Databricks Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626328/apache-spark-data-generator-function-on-databricks-not-working/70717215?noredirect=1#comment125048132_70717215)

Everything is working fine. However I would like to take it to next level and send the dummy data to Azure Event Hubs:

I attempted to do this myself with the following code:

```
import dbldatagen as dg
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType, FloatType
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DecimalType, StringType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

delay_reasons = ["Air Carrier", "Extreme Weather", "National Aviation System", "Security", "Late Aircraft"]

# will have implied column `id` for ordinal of row
flightdata_defn = (dg.DataGenerator(spark, name="flight_delay_data", rows=num_rows, partitions=num_partitions)
                 .withColumn("flightNumber", "int", minValue=1000, uniqueValues=10000, random=True)
                 .withColumn("airline", "string", minValue=1, maxValue=500,  prefix="airline", random=True, distribution="normal")
                 .withColumn("original_departure", "timestamp", begin="2020-01-01 01:00:00", end="2020-12-31 23:59:00", interval="1 minute", random=True)
                 .withColumn("delay_minutes", "int", minValue=20, maxValue=600, distribution=dg.distributions.Gamma(1.0, 2.0))
                 .withColumn("delayed_departure",  "timestamp", expr="cast(original_departure as bigint) +  (delay_minutes * 60) ", baseColumn=["original_departure", "delay_minutes"])
                 .withColumn("reason", "string", values=delay_reasons, random=True)
                )

df_flight_data = flightdata_defn.build(withStreaming=True, options={'rowsPerSecond': 100})


streamingDelays = (
  df_flight_data
    .groupBy(
      df_flight_data.flightNumber,
      df_flight_data.airline,
      df_flight_data.original_departure,
      df_flight_data.delay_minutes,
      df_flight_data.delayed_departure,
      df_flight_data.reason,
      window(df_flight_data.original_departure, "1 hour")
    )
    .count()
)

writeConnectionString = event_hub_connection_string
checkpointLocation = "///checkpoint.txt"

ehWriteConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : writeConnectionString
}


# Write body data from a DataFrame to EventHubs. 
ds = streamingDelays \
  .writeStream.format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehWriteConf) \
  .outputMode("complete") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation).start()
```

However, the Stream starts but abruptly stops and provides the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'body' not found
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write custom dataframe to eventhub from ADLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375424/how-to-write-custom-dataframe-to-eventhub-from-adls)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will check out the link, and let you know how I get on. Cheers

Comment: ok, so I changed the writeStream as follows:
```ds = streamingDelays \
  .select(F.to_json(F.struct("*")).alias("body")) \
  .writeStream.format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehWriteConf) \
  .outputMode("complete") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation).start()```

Everything appears to be going well, and then it suddently fails with the following error:
``` Job aborted due to stage failure: Provided schema doesn't match to the schema for existing state! Please note that Spark allow difference of field name: check count of fields and data type of each field.```

Comment: You need to remove checkpoint - you can’t change schema

Comment: Hi Alex, so I changed the checkpoint to ```checkpointLocation = "///checkpoint"```
But now I'm getting the following error:
```org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 43) (ip-10-172-222-58.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit```

Comment: Alex, the link you provided worked. Thank you